# how can i make UIbutton smaller? not programatically

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton

[image]how can i make this button smaller?

I have added constraints but it does not work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before Adding Constraints, Try to resize it Manually. but that can also mess whole UI up. The better solution is if you do it programmatically. Just connect the outlet and set the size of it not much of a code.